# Swift ExtensionMacro

Tags: swift, macros

I am trying to create a macro to aid in testing on a production app and have been trying a fair few different things. More detail:

#### Desired Outcome:

In the project we have a lot of protocols, so given the below:

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: Bool { get }
    func fooBar() -> Bool
}
```

We want to create a `@Testable` that would we would use like so:

```
@Testable
final class FooSpy: Foo { }
```

This class would be defined in the Testing bundle and we would expect the macro to expand into:

```
final class FooSpy: Foo {

    var bar: Bool


    var fooBarExpectation = XCTestExpectation()
    var fooBarToReturn: Bool = false
    func fooBar() -> Bool {
        fooBarExpectation.fullFill()
        return fooBarToReturn
    }

}
```

### Approach

I have managed to create a `PeerMacro` that does the above by setting the `protocol` as `@Testable`. The issue is that the macro expands in place where the protocol is and as such various testing related code doesn't compile due to lack of imports etc.

I then went on to try and make an ExtensionMacro so that I could mark the Test class as `@Testable` which is inside the test target and thus has the required imports. The issue is, that with this approach I don't seem to get access to the `Protocols` conformance requirements. Code below

```
public struct Testable: ExtensionMacro {
    private static let extractor = Extractor()

    public static func expansion(of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax, 
                                 attachedTo declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclGroupSyntax,
                                 providingExtensionsOf type: some SwiftSyntax.TypeSyntaxProtocol,
                                 conformingTo protocols: [SwiftSyntax.TypeSyntax],
                                 in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.ExtensionDeclSyntax] {
        
// Here I'm trying to get the protocol details (extractor below):
let protocolDeclaration = try extractor.extractProtocolDeclaration(from: declaration)
```

##### Extractor:

```
struct Extractor {
  func extractClassDeclaration(
    from declaration: DeclGroupSyntax
  ) throws -> ProtocolDeclSyntax {

    guard let protocolDeclaration = declaration.as(ProtocolDeclSyntax) else {
        throw TestableMacroError.invalidProtocol
    }

    return protocolDeclaration
  }
}
```

The obvious issue is that with the `ExtensionMacro`, the `declaration` is no longer the same as when it's a `PeerMacro` so this code doesn't work.

## Main Question/tl;dr

How can I (if i even can) get the protocol details from a `DeclGroupSyntax`?

Comment: Is the macro supposed to work with *any* protocol? In that case it is not possible. Swift Macros operate on the AST only, you cannot get information about what a protocol's requirements are unless the macro is applied to the protocol declaration.

Comment: How about writing a source generator instead? Source generators are a lot more powerful than macros.

Comment: yeah i thought that may be the case re protocol requirements. I'll take a look at source generator...